# Is there a way to precheck if a foreign key ID exists in its respective file or files, prior to post, using Entity Framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

Let me explain, we are using a Blazor application which uses Api's to access the database through Entity Framework Core. I have an application that is importing data in from a spreadsheet. The data is expected to be posted (inserted) into a file. That is not really an issue, but the question comes in the validation step, I have 7 foreign key values (which are also in the file being imported from the spreadsheet) in the table I am trying to insert rows into. If any one of  those foreign key values do not exist in the respective tables, the insert will throw an error on the Foreign Key Constraint violation, which is valid.

So, this is a question about refactoring, I have a working project, I am looking to educate myself and to make this project run more efficiently. My colleague (architect) without looking at the code said I could to my validation set with 1 GET using inner joins to the 7 respective tables, I am trying to validate that claim, as I don't know and he isn't available to show me. And this is about to go through a code review and the reviewer is extremely judgmental on code that he is reviewing:

There are 2 key points that I am trying to resolve:

1. In the validation step (api) can I combine the 7 GET by ID (foreign key) from 7 trips to the database, into 1 GET?
2. In the insertion step (POST api), can I skip the validation step and post  and commit the good rows, and send back a list of the bad rows. The second question I think is what my colleague is referring to and I agree with this approach, but the first question is really where I am perplexed. As I mentioned I don't see how you can one statement or GET on 7 different tables, if the main table does not have the primary key value inserted.

In order to prevent the foreign key constraint I have 7 GETS by ID of each foreign key value and a colleague said to me, you can do all of that is one SQL statement using Inner joins. Of course I understand using inner joins in sql or LINQ and I respect my colleague's advice, but I just don't see how this works if main insert hasn't happened yet. see my code below:

This is code calling the two api's from my Blazor application:

```
_gridData = await processor.ProcessObject<List<Data.ViewModels.BidImport>>(await apiClient.ValidateImportedBids(_bidItemSetImported));
        _gridDataValid = _gridData.Where(g => g.Valid).ToList();
        _gridDataImported = await processor.ProcessObject<List<Data.Models.Bid>>(await apiClient.ImportBids(_gridDataValid));
        _gridData = _gridData.Where(g => !g.Valid).ToList();
```

Each of these 2 api's calls will processes a List of Data to be validated (ValidateImportedBids) and then inserted (ImportBids) and return a List of Processed rows (set of bad rows from validation), set of good rows (insertion):

```
 private readonly string apiBidImport = "/bidimport";
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ValidateImportedBids(List<Data.ViewModels.BidImport> items)
        {
            _logger.LogInfo($"Validating Bid Item Set Bids{items.Count()}");

            var sentContent = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                  new Uri(_httpClient.BaseAddress + apiBidImport + "/validateimportedbids"))
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            return await SendAsync<List<Data.ViewModels.BidImport>>(sentContent);

        }
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ImportBids(List<Data.ViewModels.BidImport> items)
        {
            _logger.LogInfo($"Updating Bid Item Set Bids{items.Count()}");
            var model = new List<Bid>();
            var MappedItems = BidExtensions.Map(model, items);

            var sentContent = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
                  new Uri(_httpClient.BaseAddress + apiBidImport + "/postimportedbids"))
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            return await SendAsync<List<Bid>>(sentContent);


        }
```

and the question is on Validateimportbids, so notice I have 7 GET by ID,
We are using UnitOfWork design pattern. These are validating that the foreign key Id's exist in their respective files. And this is the Question:

Question 1:

Is there something that can be done to do 1 GET and validate all of the Foreign Keys to cut down on multiple trips to the Database, prior to POST Inserting a row into the database. My colleague said that I could do this using Inner Joins, since we are using Entity Framework. I will admit I am not an expert, but I want to understand. I don't think this is possible on the validation step because the main table that I would be joining to, does NOT have a row inserted with the new value, so I don't know how that code would work.

```
/// <summary>
/// Validation of Bids ready for Importing into Bids
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bids">Proc execution : List of bids to be validated</param>
/// <returns>Success and return the List of Validated bids and errors if found</returns>
[HttpGet("validateimportedbids")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<BidImport>>> ValidateBidItemSetImportBids([FromBody] List<BidImport> bids)
{
    _logger.LogDebug($"Validating Imported Bids");

    var returnBids = new List<BidImport>();
    foreach (var bid in bids)
    {
         
        bid.Valid = true;
        bid.Exclude = false;
        bid.ErrorMessage = null;

        var error = false;
        var ErrorMessageString = new StringBuilder();
        ErrorMessageString.Append("Error: ");

        // Bid Type Id is Required
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bid.Bid_TypeId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bid.Bid_TypeId))
        {
            error = true;
            ErrorMessageString.Append("Bid Type Id is Required");
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve the given Bid_Type Id
            var bid_TypeId = await _unitOfWork.BidTypes.Get(bid.Bid_TypeId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (bid_TypeId == null)
            {
                error = true;
                ErrorMessageString.Append("Bid Type Id is Invalid");
                 
            }
        }

        // Bid Class Id is Required
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bid.Bid_ClassId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bid.Bid_ClassId))
        {
            error = true;
            ErrorMessageString.Append("(Bid Class Id is Required)");
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve the given Bid_Class Id
            var bid_ClassId = await _unitOfWork.BidClasses.Get(bid.Bid_ClassId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (bid_ClassId == null)
            {
                error = true;
                ErrorMessageString.Append("(Bid Class Id is Invalid)");
            }
        }

        // Product Line Id is Required
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bid.ProductLineId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bid.ProductLineId))
        {
            error = true;
            ErrorMessageString.Append("(Product Line Id is Required)");
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve the given Product Line Id
            var bid_ProductLineId = await _unitOfWork.ProductLines.Get(bid.ProductLineId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (bid_ProductLineId == null)
            {
                error = true;
                ErrorMessageString.Append("(Product Line Id is Invalid)");
            }
        }

        // Distributor Group Id is Required
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bid.Distributor_GroupId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bid.Distributor_GroupId))
        {
            error = true;
            ErrorMessageString.Append("(Distributor Group Id is Required)");
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve the given Distributor Groupd Id
            var bid_DistributorGroupId = await _unitOfWork.DistributorGroups.Get(bid.Distributor_GroupId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (bid_DistributorGroupId == null)
            {
                error = true;
                ErrorMessageString.Append("(Distributor Group Id is Invalid)");
            }
        }

        // Distributor Id is Required
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bid.DistributorId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bid.DistributorId))
        {
            error = true;
            ErrorMessageString.Append("(Distributor Id is Required)");
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve the given Distributor Id
            var bid_DistributorId = await _unitOfWork.Distributors.Get(bid.DistributorId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (bid_DistributorId == null)
            {
                error = true;
                ErrorMessageString.Append("(Distributor Id is Invalid)");
            }
        }

        // SalesPerson Default Id is Required
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bid.SalesPersonDefaultId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bid.SalesPersonDefaultId))
        {
            error = true;
            ErrorMessageString.Append("(Sales Person Default Id is Required)");
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve the given Sales Person Default Id
            var bid_SalesPersonDefaultId = await _unitOfWork.SalesPeople.Get(bid.SalesPersonDefaultId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (bid_SalesPersonDefaultId == null)
            {
                error = true;
                ErrorMessageString.Append("(Sales Person Default Id is Invalid)");
            }
        }

        // Bid Status Id is Required
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bid.Bid_StatusId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bid.Bid_StatusId))
        {
            error = true;
            ErrorMessageString.Append("(Bid Status Id is Required)");
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve the given Bid Status Id
            var bid_StatusId = await _unitOfWork.BidStatuses.Get(bid.Bid_StatusId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (bid_StatusId == null)
            {
                error = true;
                ErrorMessageString.Append("(Bid Status Id is Invalid)");
            }
        }

        if (error)
        {
            bid.Valid = false;
            bid.Exclude = true;
            bid.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString.ToString();
        }

        returnBids.Add(bid);

    }
    return returnBids;
}
```

Question 2:

Here is the Post, I think my colleague is conflating the two routines and is telling me I should perform the validation and post together, He made a comment that rows that violate the foreign key constraint would be kicked back, and the rows that did not would be committed. That makes sense, and I am certain that can be coded, but the way it works now, and the reason for the validation step is that if a foreign key constraint is violated during the POST, the whole routine will end and nothing will be committed. Here is the POST routine.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Create the bid in the repository matching the submitted bid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="passedObject">The item you want to create</param>
        /// <response code="200">Returns newly created bids</response>
        /// <response code="400">Error adding the bid</response>
        [HttpPost("postimportedbids")]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        [ProducesResponseType(401)]
        [ProducesResponseType(404)]
        public async Task<ActionResult <List<Data.Models.Bid>>> Post([FromBody] List<BidImport> passedObject)
        {

            var items = passedObject;
            var model = new List<Data.Models.Bid>();
            var newBids = new List<Data.Models.Bid>();
            var MappedBids = BidExtensions.Map(model, items);
            _logger.LogDebug($"Importing Bid Set Import Bids");
            try
            {
                // Loop through the model and generate a new BidId
                foreach(var bid in MappedBids)
                {
                    bid.Id = await _unitOfWork.Bids.GetNextBidNumber().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await _unitOfWork.Bids.Add(bid);
                    var result = await _unitOfWork.Complete().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    newBids.Add(bid);
                }

                return newBids;
                 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("Error Inserting Imported Bids");
            }

        }
    }
}
```